# Database call results in view taking very long to load

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/regressionTest")
    public String home(Model model, @ModelAttribute CleanupTitles cleanupTitles) {
        applicationToEnvStatus = MappingUtil
                .getApplicationToEnvStatusMapping(databaseOperation);

        model.addAttribute("parameters", new Parameters());
        model.addAttribute("cleanupTitle", cleanupTitles);

        cleanupTitles.setTitles(databaseOperation.getTitle());

        return "home";
    }
```

MappingUtil class

```
public class MappingUtil {

    private enum Environment {
        dev, stage, prod
    }

    private static Map<String, String> applicationToStatus;
    private static Map<String, List<String>> applicationToEnvStatus;

    public static Map<String,List<String>> getApplicationToEnvStatusMapping(
            DatabaseOperation databaseOperation) {

        applicationToStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();
        applicationToEnvStatus = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for (Environment e : Environment.values()) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());

            applicationToStatus = databaseOperation
                    .getApplicationToEnvMapping(e.toString());

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : applicationToStatus
                    .entrySet()) {

                List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
                li.add(e.toString());
                li.add(entry.getValue());

                applicationToEnvStatus.put(entry.getKey(), li);

            }

            //System.out.println(e.toString() + "  " + applicationToStatus);
        }

        System.out.println(applicationToEnvStatus);

        return applicationToEnvStatus;

    }
```

Database call

```
public Map<String, String> getApplicationToEnvMapping(String envName) {

        String sqlQuery = "select application_name,is_completed from (select application_name,is_completed from rtf_run_status where env='"
                + envName + "' order by date_created desc) where rownum<=3";


        Map<String, String> applicationToStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();

        jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new ResultSetExtractor<Map>() {

            @Override
            public Map extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                    DataAccessException {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    applicationToStatus.put(rs.getString("application_name"),
                            rs.getString("is_completed"));
                }
                return applicationToStatus;
            }

        });

        return applicationToStatus;

    }
```

The controller is making 2 db calls to: **a)** `MappingUtil.getApplicationToEnvStatus()` and **b)** `cleanupTitles.setTitles()`. This results in view taking a lot of time to load. The result set returned from each query is around 4-5.

What would be the best approach to load view at a faster response time? Should I execute db calls in a new Thread or is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: what are you doing in those calls to be so slow? check if you are loading more details than needed if you have some relationship not LAZY and then you are doing much more queries than needed. Also if the DB actions are not related with the view results you could use some Queue system and would work faster

Comment: I think you need to show us the DB calls. There is not much of a starting point from just seeing the controller.

Comment: @OlarAndrei added db call code

Comment: Is this production code?! It has concurrency issues, it has sql injection issues... Your query is executed 3 times, it has a `rownum` attribute (assuming you are using Oracle or the likes), which still builds the whole result (on the db) and returns a few rows. With large sets, this is still slow.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please help me with what i can do to improve the performace..i need the top 3 results for each env (dev,stage,prod)..should i run the db call method in parallel for the 3 envs.

Comment: You are guessing, guessing in programming is always wrong. Measure and see where the issues are. Next to that, as stated, fix your concurrency and sql injection issues. Also imho your code is flawed in more ways then that (you should use a dao and not some static accessor method, which is already the wrong thing to do but not related to your performance issue). As stated, measure. Also you only post part of your code, there can be many more thing wrong with your code. 1 thing to start with is use a proper connection pool (my guess is you are using the `DriverManagerDataSource` instead.